# SAS Using Data Set to Create Other Data Sets

Tags: sas

I am supposed to create a summary data set containing the mean, median, and standard deviation broken down by gender and group (using the CLASS statement). Using this summary data set, create four other data sets (in one DATA step) as follows:

(1) grand mean
(2) stats broken down by gender
(3) stats broken down by group
(4) stats broken down by gender and group

Given the hint to use the CHARTYPE option.

I provided my attempted solution, but I don't think I did it in the way asked.

```
DATA CLINICAL;
   *Use LENGTH statement to control the order of
    variables in the data set;
   LENGTH PATIENT VISIT DATE_VISIT 8;
   RETAIN DATE_VISIT WEIGHT;
   DO PATIENT = 1 TO 25;
      IF RANUNI(135) LT .5 THEN GENDER = 'Female';
      ELSE GENDER = 'Male';
      X = RANUNI(135);
      IF X LT .33 THEN GROUP = 'A';
      ELSE IF X LT .66 THEN GROUP = 'B';
      ELSE GROUP = 'C';
      DO VISIT = 1 TO INT(RANUNI(135)*5);
         IF VISIT = 1 THEN DO;
             DATE_VISIT = INT(RANUNI(135)*100) + 15800;
             WEIGHT = INT(RANNOR(135)*10 + 150);
         END;
         ELSE DO;
            DATE_VISIT = DATE_VISIT + VISIT*(10 + INT(RANUNI(135)*50));
            WEIGHT = WEIGHT + INT(RANNOR(135)*10);
         END;
         OUTPUT;
         IF RANUNI(135) LT .2 THEN LEAVE;
      END;
   END;
   DROP X;
   FORMAT DATE_VISIT DATE9.;
RUN;
PROC MEANS DATA=CLINICAL;
CLASS GENDER GROUP;
OUTPUT OUT=SUMMARY
       MEAN=
       MEDIAN=
       STDDEV= / AUTONAME;
RUN;
```

Comment: This is an excellent example of how to ask a homework-type question: has the complete problem, and has a complete attempted solution including example data. As a reminder, on homework-type problems the point is to teach _how_ not _what_, so answers should point the asker in the direction of the answer and not simply provide it directly.

Answer (score 1):

No, what they're asking you to do is:

1. Use the `OUTPUT` statement in `PROC MEANS` to create a summary dataset.  Choose the appropriate `TYPES` and `CLASS` values in `PROC MEANS` such that *all four* sets of data are represented on the output.
2. Using a single data step that has four dataset names on the `data` statement, selectively output those rows to the correct dataset.  You would use the `_TYPE_` variable to determine which dataset a row  would be output to.

`CHARTYPES` just means your `_TYPE_` variable will look like `1001` instead of `9` (the binary representation, basically).  `1001` indicates which class variable is used (the first and the fourth) to create that breakout.  (With only two class variables, you would have values `00`, `01`, `10`, `11` possible).  This is sometimes easier for non-programmers who aren't used to thinking in binary (these values would be `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` in decimal without `CHARTYPES` and thus might be more difficult for you to tell which corresponds to which variable).

Comment: Thanks! If I do this correctly, the program will be shorter than it is now, right?

Comment: It won't be shorter in lines of code; assuming your first data step (that creates the code) is needed in its full length, which I don't know one way or the other, the `proc means` section will be a bit shorter but the data step will be a few lines longer.  But more importantly you'll only hit the bigger dataset once, not four times, which will speed up the program  (if that dataset were actually very big).

Comment: 'DATA GRAND GENDER GROUP GENDERGROUP;'
  SET NEW;
   IF _TYPE_ = '1111' then OUTPUT GRAND and OUTPUT GENDER and OUTPUT GROUP and OUTPUT GENDERGROUP;
RUN;'

I am not sure how the data statement works. Do I list the 4 dataset names? I am not sure how _TYPE_ is supposed to work. Could you give me an example?

Comment: Other than the `and` bit, then you have it right.  You need to choose which to output to based on `_type_`; each `_type_` value goes to a different dataset.  This should be covered in your SAS text, or if not, look around on google - it's fairly well covered, such as [here](http://libguides.library.kent.edu/SAS/SubsetData), under "splittling a dataset".

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to post code in comment, sorry about that. And okay, I'll look into that.

Comment: Yep - except you need to use `_TYPE_` and your dataset-names.  But that's the idea.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter before I meant to. I will post what I tried in a sec.

Comment: I have two class variables, gender and group, so wouldn't I just have 2 characters for '##'?

Comment: IF _TYPE_='11' THEN OUTPUT GRAND
IF _TYPE_='10' THEN OUTPUT GENDER; 
IF _TYPE_='01' THEN OUTPUT GROUP;
IF _TYPE_='11' THEN OUTPUT GENDERGROUP;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139409/discussion-between-john-h-and-joe).